# How to get the initial validation message from Input in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a number input (using Material UI `Input`) with min max set. If a user types in a number higher than the max, I can get the validation message from `event.target.validationMessage` during `onChange` event. This works so far when a user is inputting on an empty number input field.

Now say I initialised my state with an initial value that is higher than the max already, how and when should I access the `event.target.validationMessage` as this is before the user input (i.e. no `onChange` event yet)?

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shamir-1fg7h

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = (props) => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="10"
        defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
        onChange={(event) => setMsg(event.target.validationMessage)}
      ></input>
      <span>{msg}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Type 0 below to see the error message</label>
      <Input defaultValue="1" />
      <label>Should show error message straight away</label>
      <Input defaultValue="100" />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: can you post a fiddler link?

Comment: did you tried to use an useEffect at the first render of the page and another for user input?

Comment: @Nirus I've created an example here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shamir-1fg7h

Comment: interesting.. is there any reason you want to capture the error message from `validationMessage` on initial render too for defaultValue? . I would suggest you to validate the `props.defaulValue` before setting it to `input` and set `msg` programatically on valid error.

Comment: @Nirus just utilising the out-of-the-box validation rather than re-implementing the validation logic again.

Comment: okay i guess you got confused with how the validation is handled. You are expecting an UI interaction validation to work for programatic errors. All those `min`, `max` ... etc are all validation for user actions. You cannot expect program error to popup because you are setting `defaultValue` programatically & that should be handled programatically.

Comment: @Nirus the Input control does validate defaultValue the same as if it is a user input. Try to hover the mouse pointer over the second input box, you can see the validationMessage has already been set.

Comment: i dont see it. I did try to hover and nothing was set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick (or at least be a start):

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = (props) => {
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState();
  // the added part
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current.validationMessage) setMsg(ref.current.validationMessage);
  }, [ref]);
  // the added part
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={ref}
        type="number"
        min="1"
        max="10"
        defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
        onChange={(event) => setMsg(event.target.validationMessage)}
      ></input>
      <span>{msg}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>Type 0 below to see the error message</label>
      <Input defaultValue="1" />
      <label>Should show error message straight away</label>
      <Input defaultValue="100" />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-herschel-si07u?file=/src/index.js)

---

Remember that `target` is basically a ref to your input.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works nicely. But do you think there is a way not to render twice on page load (1st the console log undefined 2nd the console log the validationMessage, probably from the `useEffect` `setMsg`)?

Comment: You'll quickly have to stop worrying about renders. React is highly optimized and you won't notice this rerender. There are cases though that rerendering might cause delays, like when each keystroke triggers a rerender of a huge part of the tree.

Comment: I’m afraid that won’t be possible since the only way to modify msg is to call setMsg and the latter will automatically trigger a rerender. Also, remember that useEffect is called after the component has been rendered. To have a reference at all to the input, the input has to be rendered once. May I ask why you don’t want the two renders?

Comment: Also note that the call to setMsg in onChange will also trigger a rerender. That’s how React works.